# Writing a 2d Java LWJGL game

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl, tile

All the game tutorials I've sen on 2d games are tile based. Does someone know a Java tutorial non-tile based games, like Limbo for instance?

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the purpose of tiles. Everything doesn't need to be squares, things can still have complex shapes, though tiles are used to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion "wing it" I have always considered the tile thing more of a box concept so that you can manage it more easily but I have always found it more confusing, to say the least I have given up on searching for non tile-based tutorials and am now winging it or so to speak but it still remains important be able to see a problem for what it really is.